# Creating dictionary key and value from Variables giving syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to create dictionary by providing key and value from variables,
but I get syntax error:

```
disk_to_dm_dict = {}

for line in dm_name:
    match =  re.search(lun_reg,line)
    if match:
        lun=match.group(6)
        dm=match.group(8)
        print lun
        print dm
        #Create Dictionary with key= LUN and Value=dm
        disk_to_dm_dict['%s']%lun = dm
```

But I get error

```
 File "read_lun.py", line 42
    disk_to_dm_dict["%s"]%lun = dm
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `%` operator to the *string*, not to the result of `disk_to_dm_dict["%s"]`. Python is complaining you are trying to assign to the outcome of `something % something_else` here.

Move the operator *inside* the `[...]` brackets to apply to the `"%s"` string:

```
disk_to_dm_dict["%s" % lun] = dm
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an actual syntax error in the last line, here is the fixed variant:

```
disk_to_dm_dict['%s' % lun] = dm
```

Answer (score 0):

`lun` is already a string, which means that the key is in the required format. You can just do this:

```
disk_to_dm_dict[lun] = dm
```

To fix your code directly try:

```
disk_to_dm_dict['%s' % lun] = dm
```

That is move the `% lun` to be adjacent to the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add key:value pair to dictionary using below snippet

```
disk_to_dm_dict[lun] = dm
```

Simple!